# How to edit a StringListProperty value in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I would like to edit the value of a StringListProperty variable on App Engine. Is it possible? I don't see any sign of editable field for a StringListProperty variable right inside the DataViewer panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit it programmatically. Not all property types can be edited in the data viewer.